# Redirect customer to another store before checkout - magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

What is the correct way to redirect customer to another store before checkout. If customer is trying to get on checkout and if store is not correct then customer store needs to be changed before checkout page is opened.

I was able to achieve that with event:

```
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index">
        ...
    </event>
```

And code for redirecting is:

```
   ....
   $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($customer->getStore());
   $path = $store->getBaseUrl().'checkout';
   $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($path)->sendResponse();
   exit();
```

**Problem:**
Customer is successfully moved to another store and accessed checkout but the problem is that checkout summary with cart totals is not reloaded and prices are still the ones from previous store, only after page refresh cart prices are changed to the ones from that new store.

How can I immediatelly get correct checkout summary totals withoud need to refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my question after further investigation:

I have just changed quote store id in cart:

```
            ...
            $store = $this->storeManager->getStore($customer->getStore());
            $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($this->cart->getQuote()->getId());
            $quote->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $quote->setDataChanges(true);
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
            $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($this->cart->getQuote()->getId());
            $this->cart->setQuote($quote)->save();
            ...
```